# How to set width and height of Tbody in HTML table

Tags: html

I have a table with some rows and columns, which also includes a `<TBody>`.
What I want is to set the height and width of `TBody` different to the `table`.

Code as below :

```
<tbody id ='some id' style="display:none;" >
  <tr>
    <td style="border-right-color:transparent;" ></td>  
    <td ></td>          
    <td style="font-size:10px;">dddd</td>   
    <td style="font-size:10px;">vvv</td>            
  </tr>         
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set height using CSS. Do not give spaces inside `id`s:

```
<tbody id='someid' style="display:none; height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-right-color:transparent;" ></td>
    <td ></td>
    <td style="font-size:10px;">dddd</td>
    <td style="font-size:10px;">vvv</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```